# How can I exclude all *services.ts for `ng test --code-coverage`?

Tags: javascript, angular6, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-coverage

Under my **Angular 6** I am running the following command to unit test and generate code code coverage report:

```
ng test --browsers=Chrome --watch=false --code-coverage
```

It is working fine and writing code coverage report in coverage folder.

In this I got all files and directory coverage report:

But I want to exclude specific type of files  let say :

all files which have the service prefix: `*.service.ts`

i ve told to do that in **angular.json** :

```
 "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/*.service.ts"],
```

But that didn't work

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Test.ts file you have to write this as below:

```
const context = require.context('', true, /\.component.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
"codeCoverageExclude": [
  "/**/*service*.ts"
]
```